# Vimeo API Make Call Based on Drupal Variable

Tags: php, drupal, vimeo-api

I'm using the Vimeo API php library and hoping to return a result set based on a video ID. I'm trying to populate the Vimeo ID from a separate field in Drupal where I have pasted it in, but when I pass a variable through $lib->request, I don't get a response.

The following returns a response as expected:

```
$video = $lib->request('/me/videos/249687303');
```

But this will not return a response:

```
$video = $lib->request('/me/videos/'.$vimeoid.'');
```

I don't think it's a syntax problem because if I specify 249687303 as a variable in the code - that works. It's only when I try and use the variable coming from the Drupal field. I have verified the field does not contain any additional formatting, it's plain text, no styling, no tags. When printing the Drupal field variable, the data is correct, I'm not really sure what is happening, other than perhaps things aren't happening in the right order.

I'm handing the API call using a computed field, if that makes any difference. My hope is to simply bring in the Vimeo ID from a separate field, make the API call, and return my video array data.

Comment: check the position of your first `.`

Comment: Thank you, that was actually a typo. It was fixed in my code but, still no luck.

Comment: Do you have a way of checking/dumping the exact request uri made to the API?